# SQL Server : How to find duplicated rows value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find a duplicate number more than 4 in rows value.

If you have to find a number that is repeated more than four times, and it is not if you repeat it more than four times in a combination of other numbers.

This table is test2:

```
num1   num2  num3  num4  num5  numb6
--------------------------------------
 1      1     1     2     3      4
 1      1     1     1     3      4
 1      2     3     4     5      6
 1      2     2     1     4      5
```

My SQL query:

```
-- CTE
;WITH TEMP(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        RIGHT(num1) AS num1,
        RIGHT(num2) AS num2,
        RIGHT(num3) AS num3,
        RIGHT(num4) AS num4,
        RIGHT(num5) AS num5,
        RIGHT(num6) AS num6
    FROM 
        test2   
)
-- select duplicate number
SELECT 
    num1, num2, num3,
    num4, num5, num6,
    COUNT (CASE 
             WHEN num1 IN (num2, num3, num4, num5, num6)
                THEN 1
          END) +
    COUNT (CASE
             WHEN num2 IN (num3, num4, num5, num6)
                THEN 1
           END) + 
    COUNT (CASE
             WHEN num3 IN (num4, num5, num6)
                THEN 1
           END) +
    COUNT (CASE
             WHEN num4 IN (num5, num6)
                THEN 1
           END) +
    COUNT (CASE
             WHEN num5IN (num6)
                THEN 1
           END) AS countNum
FROM 
    TEMP
GROUP BY 
    num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6
```

I get a result like this:

```
num1   num2  num3  num4  num5  numb6  countNum
----------------------------------------------
 1      1     1     1     3      4       4
 1      2     2     1     4      5       4
```

but I need to get this instead:

```
num1   num2  num3  num4  num5  numb6  countNum
----------------------------------------------
 1      1     1     1     3      4        4
```

or I need get data

```
num1   num2  num3  num4  num5  numb6
------------------------------------
 1      1     1     1     3      4
```

Comment: there is fixed 6 columns??

Comment: What are the columns? num1, num2, num3, num4,num5, num6?

Comment: What have you tried so far? add your current sql query.

Comment: The six columns are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apply`!

```
select t.*, v.cnt
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) num, count(*) as cnt
      from (values (num1), (num2), (num3), (num4), (num5), (num6)
           ) v(num)
      group by num
      order by count(*) desc
     ) v
where v.cnt >= 4;
```

Not only is this less prone to error than massive `case` expressions.  It could even have better performance.

Comment: i get message "The multi-part identifier "v.cnt" could not be bound."

Comment: I changed "where num > 4" to "where cnt > 4", I could get the value I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution:

```
;with temp_data as (

select  1  as num1 ,    1 as num2 ,    1 as num3 ,    2  as num4 ,   3  as num5 ,    4  as num6 union all
select  1  as num1 ,    1 as num2 ,    1 as num3 ,    1  as num4 ,   3  as num5 ,    4  as num6 union all
select  2  as num1 ,    2 as num2 ,    2 as num3 ,    3  as num4 ,   2  as num5 ,    6  as num6 
)
SELECT * 
FROM temp_data
where 3=(CASE WHEN num1=num2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num1=num3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num1=num4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num1=num5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num1=num6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
3=(CASE WHEN num2=num1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num2=num3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num2=num4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num2=num5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num2=num6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
3=(CASE WHEN num3=num1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num3=num2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num3=num4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num3=num5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num3=num6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
3=(CASE WHEN num4=num1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num4=num3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num4=num2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num4=num5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num4=num6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
3=(CASE WHEN num5=num1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num5=num2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num5=num4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num5=num3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num5=num6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
OR
3=(CASE WHEN num6=num1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num6=num2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num6=num4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num6=num3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
(CASE WHEN num6=num5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
;
```

output:

```
num1    num2    num3    num4    num5    num6
1        1       1       1       3      4
2        2       2       3       2      6
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=a1c96e69d01e7c9b013952ffe04e3d94)

Comment: @seungyong . . . This is *way* more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I think so, too. I'd like to know an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code: this may help you,

```
select num1,num2,num3,num5 from dup
group by num1,num2,num3,num5
having count(num1)>1 and count(num2)>1 and count(num3)>1 and count(num5)>1
```